# Coldfusion saving variables without going to another page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to write a program that is basically one page but has many features on that one page. My question is how do I save variables to use if its always the same page. I try using bootstrap for a few pop up questions but I am not sure how I can save ColdFusion variables and coming back to the same page.

In this example it shows my main page that is always up. When you click print labels a bootstrap question pops up asking what number they would like to start printing labels at. How can I save that variable upon accept in coldfusion?

Because really the accept button closes the bootstrap but its not like I am leaving this page to go to another to save a session variable or anything. All the buttons on this page basically will be doing something similar to this. Just like if you click the new button. So how do I save variables without going to another page? Do I try to refresh the page with saving the variable somehow? Just not sure since the page never goes to another page.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function(){
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

        var LabelNum =

            $.ajax({
                // the location of the CFC to run
                  url: "example_cf7_proxy.cfm"
                // send a GET HTTP operation
                , type: "get"
                // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
                , dataType: "json"
                // send the data to the CFC
                , data: {
                    // send the ID entered by the user
                     LabelNum: $("#LabelNum").val()
                }
                // this gets the data returned on success
                , success: function (data){
                    // this uses the "jquery.field.min.js" library to easily populate your form with the data from the server
                    $("#dealerForm").formHash(data);
                }
                // this runs if an error
                , error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // show error
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });

    });

});
```

**example_cf7_proxy.cfm**

```
<!---// this acts as a proxy to our CFC //--->
<cfinvoke
    component="example"
    method="#url.method#"
    argumentCollection="#url#"
    returnVariable="results"
        />

<!---// convert the results to JSON using the CFJSON component //--->
<cfset json = createObject("component", "cfjson") />

<cfcontent reset="true" /><cfoutput>#json.encode(results, false)#</cfoutput>
```

But I am getting this error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/3/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function(){
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
        $('#NewDealer').modal('hide');

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<form id="dealerForm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <label for="ItemID">ITEM ID</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemID" id="ItemID"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Search" id="Search" value="SEARCH"/>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="Qty">QTY</label>
                        <select name="Qty" id="Qty" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="Dealers"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected></option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select> <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="button"  name="New" value="NEW" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NewDealer"/>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="table"></label>
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="centered" for="DueToday">DUE TODAY @ 5:00 (10/1/15)</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="centered" for="DueToday">DUE 10/02/15 @ 5:00</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label for="Buttons"></label>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Report" value="REPORT">
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LabelMaker">PRINT LABELS</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="LogItIn" value="LOG IT IN">
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="CompleteIt" value="COMPLETE IT">
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="ExitBtn" style="display:none">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Exit" id="Exit" value="EXIT">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Label Maker Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="LabelMaker" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Label Maker</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label for="LabelNum">Please enter label start number:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LabelNum" id="LabelNum">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary label_accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Label Maker Modal -->

<!-- New Dealer Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="NewDealer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="NewDealerLabel">New Dealer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label for="NewDealerName">Please enter the dealer name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewDealerName" id="NewDealerName">
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dealer_accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End New Dealer Modal -->
</form>
```

Comment: You use javascript to make an AJAX request to a ColdFusion page, passing whatever data you're wanting to save.  It does that all server-side.  You probably want to go and read something like http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1515-ask-ben-building-an-ajax-jquery-and-coldfusion-powered-application.htm

Comment: Man this ajax stuff is tough I cannot get any of it to run

Comment: @Duncan any chance for some assistance with this ajax stuff iv been working on?

Comment: what does the JSON packet look like?

Comment: it actually shows the number entered in the file name webapps/dealertracking/example_cf7_proxy.cfm?LabelNum=654564

Comment: @Duncan how do I turn that number into a CF variable?

Comment: isn't there a way to grab that url and take that number and turn it into a variable